# Removing child item in ExpandableListView doesn't change on UI

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I have an ELV with some child items based off a String ArrayList which is displayed on a Fragment. For each child item, there is a delete button so a user can delete a particular item. The item will be successfully deleted from the ArrayList but it won't update on the UI there and then. I have to go to a different page and come back to it for it to be **shown** that it's removed. I've looked at some posts which refer to using the notifyDataSetChanged() or notifyDataSetInvalidated() methods for the adapter but it still doesn't update the list on the UI. I've tried using the methods in my Fragment and that doesn't work either. Am I not placing it in the correct place or am I missing something else?

getChildView method in custom ExpandableListAdapter.java class:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    int buttonToHide = SessionsActivity.whichInflate;

    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    // TextView which will hold the text of the child item
    TextView textListChild = convertView.findViewById(R.id.listItem);
    // Button to add a session (for SessionsFragment.java)
    ImageButton addButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    // Button to delete user choice session (for YourSessionsFragment.java)
    ImageButton deleteButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);

    final View finalConvertView = convertView;

    // if the int value in SessionsActivity.java is 0 -> hide the delete button, 1 -> hide the add button
    if(buttonToHide == 0) {
        deleteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else if(buttonToHide == 1) {
        addButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // Listener for the add button
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Check group position to add child to right group
            if(groupPosition == 0) {
                // Check to add session if it already hasn't beed added
                if(!sessionExists(childText, YourSessionsFragment.userSessions22)) {
                    Toast.makeText(finalConvertView.getContext().getApplicationContext(), childText + " added to your sessions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Add the session to the ArrayList
                    YourSessionsFragment.userSessions22.add(childText);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(finalConvertView.getContext().getApplicationContext(),"This session has already been added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else {
                if(!sessionExists(childText, YourSessionsFragment.userSessions23)) {
                    Toast.makeText(finalConvertView.getContext().getApplicationContext(), childText + " added to your sessions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    YourSessionsFragment.userSessions23.add(childText);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(finalConvertView.getContext().getApplicationContext(),"This session has already been added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Listener for delete button
    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Check group position to delete the right child item
            if(groupPosition == 0) {
                // Check if the session exists
                if(sessionExists(childText, YourSessionsFragment.userSessions22)) {
                    Toast.makeText(finalConvertView.getContext().getApplicationContext(), childText + " removed from your sessions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Remove it from the ArrayList
                    YourSessionsFragment.userSessions22.remove(childPosition); // Remove item from arrl
                    YourSessionsFragment.listDataChild.remove(childText); // Remove item from YourSessionsFragment class
                    _listDataChild.remove(childText); // Remove item from this class
                    YourSessionsFragment.expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Why doesn't this work???
                    YourSessionsFragment.expandableListView.setAdapter(YourSessionsFragment.expandableListAdapter);

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(finalConvertView.getContext().getApplicationContext(),"This session has already been removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else {
                if(sessionExists(childText, YourSessionsFragment.userSessions23)) {
                    Toast.makeText(finalConvertView.getContext().getApplicationContext(), childText + " removed from your sessions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    YourSessionsFragment.userSessions23.remove(childPosition); // Remove item from arrl
                    YourSessionsFragment.listDataChild.remove(childText); // Remove item from YourSessionsFragment class
                    _listDataChild.remove(childText); // Remove item from this class
                    YourSessionsFragment.expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Why doesn't this work???
                    YourSessionsFragment.expandableListView.setAdapter(YourSessionsFragment.expandableListAdapter);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(finalConvertView.getContext().getApplicationContext(),"This session has already been removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Set the text of the child item
    textListChild.setText(childText);

    return convertView;
}
```

YourSessionsFragment.java (This is where the ELV is displayed)

```
public class YourSessionsFragment extends Fragment {

public static ArrayList<String> userSessions22 = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<String> userSessions23 = new ArrayList<>();

public static ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
ExpandableListView expandableListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sessions, container, false);

    // Get the ListView
    expandableListView = view.findViewById(R.id.sessionsExpandableListView);

    // Prepare the list data
    prepareListData();

    expandableListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getContext(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // Set the list adapter and expand lists by default
    expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
    expandableListView.expandGroup(0);

    return view;
}

/**
 * Prepare the list data
 */
public void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<>();

    // Header data
    listDataHeader.add("22nd May 2018");
    listDataHeader.add("23rd May 2018");

    // Child data
    List<String> may22 = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < userSessions22.size(); i++) {
        may22.add(userSessions22.get(i));
    }

    List<String> may23 = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < userSessions23.size(); i++) {
        may23.add(userSessions23.get(i));
    }

    // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), may22);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), may23);
}
}
```

Comment: you need to update your list passed in the adapter as well..

Answer (score 0):

You are not removing it from your adapter, instead you are removing the item is pre defined lists userSessions22 and userSessions23 which have nothing to do once data is populated in the expandable list view. As your getting child text by using the following code
`final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);`
you can also create another method for removing a child from the `listDataChild`.

The last two lines of your delete button click listener

```
YourSessionsFragment.expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Why doesn't this work???
YourSessionsFragment.expandableListView.setAdapter(YourSessionsFragment.expandableListAdapter);
```

please write them as following and remove last line

```
notifyDataSetChanged(); // Why doesn't this work???
```

Comment: Ok so I'm removing the item from listDataChild (used childText as well as childPosition) from the delete button listener but it still doesn't refresh real time. Setting the adapter again doesn't make a difference too

Comment: Updated the getChildView method, specifically the delete button listener section